# Dimension error

Tags: julia, conv-neural-network

I am trying to make a cnn using flux in Julia. However I am getting the following error.

```
LoadError: [91mDimensionMismatch("")[39m
while loading untitled-65dcf75c74c0859bdf206a333b2e1081, in expression starting on line 165
#conv2d!#48(::Tuple{Int64,Int64}, ::Tuple{Int64,Int64}, ::Int64, ::Int64, ::Float64, ::Function, ::Array{Float64,4}, ::Array{Float64,4}, ::Array{Float64,4}) at conv.jl:264
(::NNlib.#kw##conv2d!)(::Array{Any,1}, ::NNlib.#conv2d!, ::Array{Float64,4}, ::Array{Float64,4}, ::Array{Float64,4}) at <missing>:0
(::NNlib.#kw##conv!)(::Array{Any,1}, ::NNlib.#conv!, ::Array{Float64,4}, ::Array{Float64,4}, ::Array{Float64,4}) at <missing>:0
#conv#58(::Tuple{Int64,Int64}, ::Tuple{Int64,Int64}, ::Int64, ::Function, ::Array{Float64,4}, ::Array{Float64,4}) at conv.jl:29
(::NNlib.#kw##conv)(::Array{Any,1}, ::NNlib.#conv, ::Array{Float64,4}, ::Array{Float64,4}) at <missing>:0
track(::Flux.Tracker.Call{Flux.Tracker.#_conv,Tuple{Array{Float64,4},TrackedArray{…,Array{Float64,4}},Tuple{Int64,Int64},Tuple{Int64,Int64}}}) at Tracker.jl:41
#conv#31(::Tuple{Int64,Int64}, ::Tuple{Int64,Int64}, ::Function, ::Array{Float64,4}, ::TrackedArray{…,Array{Float64,4}}) at array.jl:321
(::NNlib.#kw##conv)(::Array{Any,1}, ::NNlib.#conv, ::Array{Float64,4}, ::TrackedArray{…,Array{Float64,4}}) at <missing>:0
(::Flux.Conv{2,NNlib.#relu,TrackedArray{…,Array{Float64,4}},TrackedArray{…,Array{Float64,1}}})(::Array{Float64,4}) at conv.jl:39
mapfoldl_impl(::Base.#identity, ::Flux.##81#82, ::Array{Float64,4}, ::Array{Any,1}, ::Int64) at reduce.jl:43
(::Flux.Chain)(::Array{Float64,4}) at basic.jl:31
loss(::Array{Float64,4}, ::Array{Any,1}) at untitled-65dcf75c74c0859bdf206a333b2e1081:150
macro expansion at train.jl:39 [inlined]
macro expansion at progress.jl:107 [inlined]
#train!#146(::Flux.Optimise.##147#149, ::Function, ::Function, ::Array{Any,1}, ::Flux.Optimise.##80#84) at train.jl:38
macro expansion at train.jl:65 [inlined]
macro expansion at progress.jl:107 [inlined]
anonymous at <missing>:?
include_string(::String, ::String) at loading.jl:522
include_string(::Module, ::String, ::String) at Compat.jl:88
(::Atom.##112#116{String,String})() at eval.jl:109
withpath(::Atom.##112#116{String,String}, ::Void) at utils.jl:30
withpath(::Function, ::String) at eval.jl:38
hideprompt(::Atom.##111#115{String,String}) at repl.jl:67
macro expansion at eval.jl:106 [inlined]

(::Atom.##110#114{Dict{String,Any}})() at task.jl:80
```

The model that I am making is as follows:

```
s=train_data(ran)
s1=zeros(1501,10,10,10)
x_tdata=[]
y_tdata=[]
for i in 1:1501 push!(x_tdata,s[i][1]) end
for i in 1:1501 push!(y_tdata,s[i][2]) end
for i in 1:1501
 for j in 1:10
  s1[i,j,:,:]=x_tdata[i][j][:][:]
  end
  end
xx= permutedims(s1, [2, 3,4, 1])

using Flux
using Flux: mse
using Flux: @epochs

model = Chain(
    Conv((2,2), 1=>32, relu),
    x -> maxpool(x, (2,2)),
    Conv((2,2), 32=>64, relu),
    x -> maxpool(x, (2,2)),
    Conv((2,2), 64=>128, relu),
    x -> maxpool(x, (2,2)),
    Conv((2,2), 128=>128, relu),
    x -> maxpool(x, (2,2)),
    x -> reshape(x, :, size(x, 4)),
    Dense(288, 10))

loss(x, y) = mse(model(x), y)
opt = ADAM(params(model))
using Base.Iterators: partition

trainData = []
for batch in partition(1:1500, 50)
    trainXFloat = Float64.(xx[:, :,:, batch])

    trainY = y_tdata[batch]
    push!(trainData, (trainXFloat, trainY))
end
#@show params(model)
@epochs 100 Flux.train!(loss, trainData, opt)
```

I believe the problem might be in calculating the dense layer inputs. Can someone please help me understand how to calculate that. If you think otherwise then also let me know where the error might be occurring.

Thanks for your help!